# How to calculate a field in webform?

Tags: webforms

We recently implemented a site on the Drupal environment.

We make considerable use of the amazing Webform system.
However, we encountered a need for which we did not see a solution in the existing elements in the Webform.

We need an element that can perform a simple calculation (+ - * /) between other numerical fields and\or pre-set numbers as we choose.
So that the person filling out the form will see the result of the calculation while filling out the form. Something like entering a number and multiply by X number or another number field.

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to use a computed element. [Check out this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rRlTTkwdP_o)

Comment: not exactly,  I'm looking for calculated fields that calculates while filling the form  (check this exampl on a previos platform we have (ignore the hebrew text) https://Bezalel.formtitan.com/fte7849c141623666488760

Answer (score 2):

you can use Computed twig field.
In this example it calculates the result of 5 fields (a2 + b2 + c2 + d2 + f2) only if all the fields are complete

[image]